# In vue3, I can get the form data，Why is my form not echoing？

Tags: vue.js

When I click my edit button, I can get the form data, but my form does not echo, I don't know why

here is my code

```js
watch(()=> props.modal , (newVal) => {
    modalFlag.value = newVal
    formDataRef.value.resetFields()
    formData = props.data
})
```

```js
<Form ref="formDataRef" :model="formData" :label-width="150" :rules="ruleValidate" inline>
            <Row>
                <Col span="12" />
                <FormItem label="thresholdName:" prop="paramName">
                    <DHCCInput v-model="formData.paramName" :maxlength="64" placeholder="请输入阈值名称" />
                </FormItem>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Col span="12" />
                <FormItem label="threshold:" prop="paramVal">
                    <DHCCInput v-model="formData.paramVal" :maxlength="64" placeholder="请输入阈值" />
                </FormItem>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Col span="12" />
                <FormItem label="typeData:" prop="paramType">
                    <Select style="width:200px" clearable v-model="formData.paramType" :maxlength="64"
                        placeholder="Please choose the type">
                        <Option v-for="(subItem, subIndex) in $getDicList('PARAM_TYPE')" :key="`${subIndex}_sub`"
                            :value="subItem.dicCode">{{ subItem.dicValue }}
                        </Option>
                    </Select>
                </FormItem>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Col span="12" />
                <FormItem label="describe:">
                    <DHCCInput v-model="formData.paramDesc" :maxlength="64" placeholder="please enter a description" />
                </FormItem>
            </Row>
</Form>
```

I can see that formData does have a value through console.log(formData), but my form does not echo

Comment: how is `formData` defined?  is it created using `reactive` or `ref` (if ref, you need to use `.value`)?  Does `props.data` have the exact same field names?  Some additional field definitions and example values would be helpful to show, as well as the output of your console.log